# rally copy user stories

Tags: ruby, rally

I want to copy one user story from one project to another. How to use ruby to accomplish this?

I know there is a deep copy app, but that can only copy one by one. I have thousands of user stories to manage.

Is there any function like @rally.copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no copy convenience method built in Rally api tookit.
Moving stories from one project to another within the same workspace can be done in 3 steps:

get the ref of the destination project

```
project = {"_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/2222" }
```

query on stories you want to update

```
results = @rally.find(query)
```

buldk update stories

```
results.each do |s|
    field_updates = {"Project" => project}
    s.update(field_updates)
end
```

Copying wold be more difficult since that will require reading stories from one project to get their data, and then creating new stories with that data using `@rally.create` . To avoid concurrency issues, create stories without replicating their child/parent relationships.  Only after the stories are created, you may read the newly created stories and stitch them together by updating Parent field, e.g.

get the parent's ref

```
parent = {"_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement/7777" }
```

find the stories to be updated

```
  children = @rally.find(query)
```

update

```
children.each do |s|
    field_updates = {"Parent" => parent}
    s.update(field_updates)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `rally gem`. [Rally API](http://rubygems.org/gems/rally_api)